# Intuition for inverse Laplace transform / Bromwich integral

Tags: complex-analysis, laplace-transform

I'm working in probability and statistics, and in that context I feel I have a reasonable understanding of the two-sided Laplace transform,
$$
f^\star(\lambda) = \mathscr{L}[f](\lambda) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\lambda x}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x.
$$
However, I don't have much knowledge of complex analysis, and so the general formula for its inverse, the Bromwich integral, feels rather opaque:
$$
f(x) = \mathscr{L^{-1}}[f^\star](x) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma-i\infty}^{\gamma+i\infty} e^{\lambda x}f^\star(\lambda)\,\mathrm{d}\lambda.
$$
Presumably, if I *really* want to understand the inverse Laplace transform, there's no substitute for studying complex analysis up to the point of being able to make sense of and evaluate such an integral.

However, as a tourist in the area, I'm wondering if there is some kind of intuition, geometrical or otherwise, that can help me understand why the second equation above would be the inverse of the first one. It would be helpful also to have some intuition about how the value of $\gamma$ should be chosen, and when and why the inverse exists and is unique.

I understand Fourier transforms and I have a reasonable intuition for complex numbers in general, but I haven't studied complex analysis and don't know how to integrate complex functions.

Comment: There is a short explanation of complex integrals here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral#Complex_line_integral  It is a quite natural concept. The integral is a limit of Riemann sums just like in the real case. Instead of integrating along a real interval, you integrate along a general curve in the complex plane. You may also compare the concept with line integrals of functions of several variables.

Comment: @Gary thank you, that's helpful. There still seems to be some ground to cover in between knowing that and seeing why the Bromwich integral is the inverse of the Laplace transform, though.

Comment: The formula can be derived (at least formally) via the inverse Fourier transfrom. To determine $\gamma$ and to see why the natural contour of integration is a vertical line, you need to know some complex analysis (e.g., residues). See, e.g., http://www.staff.city.ac.uk/~george1/laplace_residue.pdf  I highly recommend studying some basic complex analysis, it is a beautiful (and highly useful) subject.